# How do I create a ResourceDictionary in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to follow this example:

```
public class App : Application
{
    public App ()
    {
        var buttonStyle = new Style (typeof(Button)) {
            Setters = {
                ...
                new Setter { Property = Button.TextColorProperty,   Value = Color.Teal }
            }
        };

        Resources = new ResourceDictionary ();
        Resources.Add ("buttonStyle", buttonStyle);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

[Global Styles](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/application/)

But it doesn't work / recognize the `new ResourceDictionary()`. Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Define 'doesn't work'. Do you get any errors? If yes, what are they?

Comment: You still have to set the Style on an actual button after adding it to the resource dictionary. For example, `<button Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}"/>`

Comment: `using Xamarin.Forms;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add to your setter to style's `Setters` collection too. Code in PCL:

```
        using Xamarin.Forms; 

        .....
        this.Resources = new ResourceDictionary();
        var style = new Style(typeof(Button));
        style.Setters.Add(new Setter { Property = Button.TextColorProperty,   Value = Color.Teal });

        Resources.Add("MyButtonStyle", style);
```

Answer (score 1):

You create class in resource file

```
namespace MyNameSpace.Resources
{
    public static class Styles
    {
        public static Style ButtonStyle = new Style(typeof(Button))
        {
            Setters = {
                new Setter { Property = Button.TextColorProperty,   Value = Color.Teal }

            }
        };
    }
}
```

In your xaml.cs file you can use directly like

```
MyBtn.Style = Styles.ButtonStyle;
```

Answer (score 1):

Application should already have a resource dictionary, especially if defined in the XAML.

Check if `Resources` is null

Check if `Application.Current.Resources` is null

if both are null you can create a `new ResourceDictionary()`, you may need to include `using Xamarin.Forms;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement resource dictionary.

Create a class like so:

```
public class MyResourceDictionary : ResourceDictionary
{

}
```

Then in your code you should be able to do:

```
Resources = new MyResourceDictionary();
Resources.Add("ButtonStyle",buttonStyle);
```